# Rich text field is not showing the published (EVOQ) version of inner app

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

First off I would like to say your product is amazing! Has made the job of inheriting an old DNN instance a much more intuitive experience.

Apologies if this is really simple thing I'm missing but I'm at a dead end after scouring the docs and internet.

I'm using Evoq content and up until the start of the week the publishing workflow had been working fine rich text WISIWIG fields but it seems something has changed. Now when publishing changes any apps that are embedded in rich content fields display the demo item when not logged in.

I've recreated the issue on a smaller scale to illustrate the problem:

When logged in it looks as expected - on the left is a button that's placed directly onto the page, on the right is a button inside a rich text field:

[logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRw8T.png)

And when logged out:

[logged out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXgjS.png)

As you can see the button that is embedded as a rich text field is displaying the demo item.

I've gone through all of the content items and ensured that they are set to publish and not draft or hide and ensured the page is set to published in DNN.

Aldo I've double checked how the fields are setup but as this was working previously, I'm doubtful that this is the issue but for clarity here is how the fields look in the model:

[Rich text field model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mWI1.png)

And it's rendered to the page using:

```
@{
  var renderSvc = GetService<IRenderService>();
}

@renderSvc.All(Content, field: "BodyContentBlocks", merge: Content.Body)
```

I've been scouring the docs and internet for hints of what might be going on but the closest I could find was this thread on [github](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1573) but it doesn't seem to be quite the same issue.

Any help would be massively apricated as this issue has cropped up just before moving to our production server (as they always do!) after working as expected for a couple of months. Let me know if you need any more info from me and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Evoq has a page-workflow feature which is technically undocumented. 2sxc got a sponsor a few years ago who paid for the implementation but there are limitations to it. Some background:

1. Some data in 2sxc can be clearly assigned to a module or page - such as content added directly
2. Other data cannot be assigned to a page - such as a blog post

Because of this, the logic is to first determine if something is `partOfPage` and if yes - and workflow is active - then it will be set to be a draft. This way the end users don't see it.

Upon page-publish, everything that is `partOfPage` will be published, so the draft will become the live data.

I assume the detection of this was never implemented for inner content - I think inner-content was actually developed later. Because of this, I assume the toolbars for the inner-content-item tell the UI it's part of the page (resulting in draft), but the publish cycle doesn't know about this, since it's internally a sub-entity (which is just like a tag on a blog - not part of a page).

This is difficult to fix. A proper fix would require 2sxc to be modified to make sure that inner-content is never seen as part-of-page, OR that it's taken into account when publishing. Both of these options would probably take ca. 3 days of dev on 2sxc side and would only happen if we have a sponsor.

A workaround is to disable the Evoq-integration so the page publishing wouldn't happen. I believe there is a feature for this - and AFAIK you don't even have to become a Patron (which I highly recommend to support our thousands of hours of work):

[image]

Or you could manually try to publish it, but that will be difficult. Note that most of us will be on x-mas vacation so we won't be answering questions till mid Jan.

Summary of options

1. Avoid inner content for now
2. Disable Evoq Page Workflow in 2sxc
3. Manually publish the items (very difficult, needs super-user permissions because it's an unusual thing to publish)
4. Get some budget ca. 3 days to sponsor the feature https://2sxc.org/contact but wait till end of January
5. A mix of short-term solution + sponsoring

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. I'm not able to work on this now until the new year but I will be recommending the solutions outlined here and see what's viable. Thanks again for your time and your great product!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay on this, I've been waiting for a decision. I'm going to close the question as we have been able to work around the issue for now with the help of your last comment. Avoiding inner content is working well enough for our use case. Thanks for your time and help and for making an amazing product!

Comment: great, best mark as answered :)

Comment: This is not an answer...